# Get Particular Columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxRIs.png)

I have three tables with the schema as defined in the image, I want id, title, content, published, created_at from posts table, username from Users table and sum of total votes for a post In the votes table, for every vote by a user, a new entry is created consisting of post id and user id

I tried this out -

```py
all_posts = db.query(
    func.count(models.Vote.post_id), models.User.username,
    models.Post.id, models.Post.title,
    models.Post.content, models.Post.created_at
).filter(
    models.Post.user_id == models.User.id,
    models.Vote.post_id == models.Post.id
).group_by(
    models.User.username, models.Post.id, models.Post.title,
    models.Post.content, models.Post.created_at
)
```

Output -
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIWxi.png)

```
username: 'User1'
id: 1
title: Title 1
content: Content 1
created_at: '2021-11-18T12:13:09.236169+05:30'
```

In the query i have specified i want votes count also but in the output I am not getting the votes count

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include the output (as text) here in this question. What is wrong with the output?

Comment: @Donat I'm getting all the columns except the count of votes column

`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have foreign keys between your tables, you could try to define `relationship`s on your models.

```python
class Post(Base):
    # rest of the model omitted but unchanged
    creator = relationship("User")
    votes = relationship("Vote", back_populates="post")

class Vote(Base):
    # rest of the model omitted but unchanged
    post = relationship("Post", back_populates="votes")
```

With these new relationships, getting the count and the properties that you need is quite simple :

```python
# the joins are to avoid any unwanted cartesian products
(
    s.dbs.query(
            Post.id,
            User.username,
            func.count(Post.votes)
        )
        .join(Vote.post)
        .join(Post.creator)
        .group_by(
            Post.id,
            User.username
    ).all()
)
```